# Landsat footprint artifacts in statewide CCDC map

Tags: google-earth-engine, algorithm, landsat, land-cover

I have produced a map for New York State using CCDC as implemented in google earth engine. The map counts the number of disturbances for each pixel occurring between 1990 and 2019 (black = 0 disturbance, white = more disturbances). This map shows artifacts of the landsat scene footprints – specifically, the areas of scene overlap show more disturbances than those without scene overlap. See the striping pattern in the western part of the state. How can I mitigate this?

Disturbance count map:
[image]

Landsat scene footprints:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These stripes are indeed due to the higher density observations in the areas with scene overlap.

The [LCMAP](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S003442571930375X) project used a newer version of CCDC that includes an observation density correction (See figure 8).

Apparently the USGS [USGS pyCCD](https://github.com/repository-preservation/lcmap-pyccd) repo includes this density correction. The density correction is explained in the [COLD paper](https://www.fs.fed.us/rm/pubs_journals/2020/rmrs_2020_zhu_z001.pdf) by Zhu et al. (Also author of CCDC).  COLD code can be found [here](https://github.com/GERSL/COLD).